# how many maximum values can hold dojo's combo box

Tags: java, dojo

How to identify the maximum capacity of a `ComboBox` or `FilteringSelect` in Dojo. is there any default capacity declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as a maximum capacity. Both `ComboBox` and `FilteringSelect` are `dojo/store` based widgets. This means that the data comes directly from these stores. There are several implementations of the store API, for example:

- A memory store `dojo/store/Memory`
- A REST service based store `dojo/store/JsonRest`

These stores can be used in many cases, for comboboxes, trees, grids, ... . It would not really make sense to put a maximum capacity on it.

Of course, this doesn't mean you should store thousands of items in a Memory store, since this will cause a huge performance-issue.

So back to your question; technically you can use millions of values in your combobox, you just need the right store for the right amount of data. The JsonRest store will use a serverside storage and REST API to retrieve a subset of your data, so you will be able to use a lot more data with this store, compared to a Memory store which stores everything in memory.